# undefined method and attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I want to collect data from an input which is not in my model. So, I tried to use a "attr_accessor" but it's don't work and I don't know why ...
There is the line in my controller :

```
attr_accessor :nbr_blocs
```

And there are few parts from my form (made with simpleform) :

```
<%= simple_form_for @newsletter, method: "post", url: (gestion_newsletters_assist_step2_send_path) do |f| %>
[...]
<%= f.input :"nbr_blocs", :as => :integer, :input_html => { :maxlength => 2 } %>
[...]
<% end %>
```

And my error is : "*undefined method `nbr_blocs'*"

What can I do ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I see you're new to SO. If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It helps giving feedback, marking to others searching for the same issue, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From SimpleForm [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder):

`#input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block) ⇒ Object`

So, `:nbr_blocs` must be a attribute from `@newsletter`, not a Controller accessor. I guess you can use `simple_fields_for` for an input that is not in your model, nut I am not sure:

```
<%= simple_form_for @newsletter do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :attribute %>

  <%= simple_fields_for :not_model do |n| %>
    <%= n.input :nbr_blocs %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```